# %lf is not working in Viesul studio 13 and VisualGDB Ultimate Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2013, printf, double, lf

A problem occurred while using %lf in sprintf.

```
char ary[20];
double d = 0.1235f;
sprintf(ary, "%lf", d);
```

d : 0.12349999696016312

[result]

ary : ""

I can't find the reason why.